# XDispatchProviderInterceptor do not intercept all dispatches

Tags: c++, libreoffice

I have a c++ extension based on example in Libreoffice SDK 7.6.4.1:
`LibreOffice\sdk\examples\DevelopersGuide\Components\Addons\ProtocolHandlerAddon_cpp`

I want to extend it to intercept all actions from GUI or keyboard. Like Toolbar or MenuBar actions. Closing or Creating document, and etc. So i`m trying to use `XDispatchProviderInterception` environment. And made something like this(full code here : https://github.com/libre-office-wtf/XDispatchProviderInterceptor_question )

```
class Addon: public cppu::WeakImplHelper5<
    css::frame::XDispatch,
    css::frame::XDispatchProviderInterceptor,
    css::frame::XInterceptorInfo,
    css::lang::XInitialization,
    css::lang::XServiceInfo>
{
///all interface specific virutal function initialized
private:
css::uno::Reference<css::frame::XDispatchProviderInterception> _xRegistration;

public:
 virtual void SAL_CALL initialize(const css::uno::Sequence<css::uno::Any>& aArguments) throw(css::uno::Exception, css::uno::RuntimeException)
{
    css::uno::Reference<css::frame::XFrame> xFrame;

    if (aArguments.getLength())
    {
        aArguments[0] >>= xFrame;
    }
   _xRegistration = css::uno::Reference<css::frame::XDispatchProviderInterception>(xFrame, css::uno::UNO_QUERY);
   _xRegistration->registerDispatchProviderInterceptor(this);
}
}
```

I expect that `XDispatchProviderInterception`  in `xFrame` should provide ALL dispatches from all over the document because it is top frame in this document frame tree.
But as result(https://github.com/libre-office-wtf/XDispatchProviderInterceptor_question/blob/main/debug.log) only some dispatches going to  `XDispatchProviderInterceptor`.

- Close document window(big X) .uno:CloseFrame - YES it is
- Close document window(small x) .uno:CloseWin - YES it is

but

- File - Close - NO
- File - Exit from Libre office - NO
- File - Save - NO
- TOOLBAR - Save - NO

In (https://github.com/libre-office-wtf/XDispatchProviderInterceptor_question/blob/main/debug.log) there is  `.uno:Save`  or `.uno:SaveAs` but only on GUI drawing(as i understand) of this toolbar or menu item.

As result of my small research i want to understand:

1. How to intercept absolutely all dispatches in all ways using Interception environment?
2. Is it possible to do this at all just using only libreoffice api?
3. If not, and to do this i must fork libreoffice it self(this is rediculous hard way to this small feature) where to start this amazing research?

So as im new in libreoffice api, any help or suggestion, or link to c++ `XDispatchProviderInterceptor`  inside Libreoffice addin example would be appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/DispatchCommands: "Parts of this page are generated with a script which analyzes a number of source files."

Comment: Thank you very much for reply! Of cause understanding of commands meaning very important here. But I'm trying to find a way to properly intercept all events from the GUI to the model. So it is not solve my question.